# esxi 5.1 (free) reduce vmdk size (not zero the data, reduce size by a certain amount)

Tags: vmware-esxi, shrink

I have set 100GB as the limit of my VMDK.  I can reduce the size by using the vmkfstools -k my.vmdk

What I would really like to do is take 20GB off the thick size of the disk.

Any advice? I would prefer something in the CLI vs using the converter but open to advice :).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the drive from a [thick-provisioned disk to a thin-proivisoned disk](http://www.bonusbits.com/main/HowTo:Convert_a_VMDK_from_Thick_to_Thin_on_ESX). We're missing a little information, though. How much of the 100GB is in use right now? If it's say, 60-70GB, is this exercise worth it?

The process is simple in a vSphere situation where you have the ability to migrate the VM to another datastore. If you need to do this via the command line, the [steps are more involved](http://www.bonusbits.com/main/HowTo:Convert_a_VMDK_from_Thick_to_Thin_on_ESX).

Comment: At least in ESXi 5.1 the vmkfstools -l my.vmdk will convert it to a thin disk as well (as mentioned in OP).  I think without going thin, the only other option I've found is using the VMware Converter.  Seems extending is easy enough but shrinking is more difficult (as I can imagine without the disk being defragged or zero'd)

Comment: Oh, notably, you linked the same thing twice.  Thanks anyway

Comment: If you use the right tool for your guest OS to consolidate data/zero free space, you can potentially reclaim data. But this is usually done in conjunction with a datastore move and a licensed copy of vSphere. That $500-$600 for the basic [vSphere Essentials](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/compare-kits.html) doesn't look so bad!